# php 7.2 A non well formed numeric value encountered test failing but why?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

ok so this is a simple unit test that is failing only with strings starting with a number.

My original class is here

```
class InstanceID implements InstanceIDInterface
{
    private $id;
    public function __construct(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

And here is the unit test

```
class InstanceIDTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
     public function testCanInitializeWithValidID()
     {
          $InstanceID = new InstanceID(3456);

          $this->assertInstanceOf('InstanceID', $InstanceID);
    }


    /**
     * @dataProvider invalidStrings
     */
    public function testNonNumericStringShouldNotBeAccepted($id)
    {
        $this->expectException(TypeError::class);
        $InstanceID = new InstanceID($id);
    }

    public function invalidStrings() {
        return [
            ["ABC1234"], // works
            ["1234WUK"], // error
            ["W1234W"], // works
            ["1234yHk92383"] // error
        ];
    }

}
```

and this is the test run result

```
There were 2 errors:

1) InstanceIDTest::testNonNumericStringShouldNotBeAccepted with data set #1 ('1234WUK')
A non well formed numeric value encountered

2) InstanceIDTest::testNonNumericStringShouldNotBeAccepted with data set #3 ('1234yHk92383')
A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

Question is why the error is not being caught by 
    $this->expectException(TypeError::class); 
line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's not an exception but a notice.

To make it a `TypeError` you need to enable strict types check with

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

at the top of your `InstanceID` file.

What's happening now is - `"1234WUK"` is implicitly converted to a `1234` integer with a notice.